# How many prime numbers are there from 43 to 60?

Tags: prime-numbers, divisor-counting-function

The question doesn't mention anything about 'inclusive' or 'exclusive'. If I include 43 in my count, there are 4 prime numbers between 43 and 60. If I exclude 43, there are 3 prime numbers. What is the most appropriate way to approach this kind of math problem?

Comment: You just count them.

Comment: As for the inclusion/exclusion of $43$, without seeing an actual question, it's hard to tell.

Comment: @scoopfaze it's a mcq question from a test. The actual question is 'How many prime numbers are there from 43 to 60?'.

Comment: Then, as José Carlos Santos pointed out, you just need to count them. If you're uncertain about whether to include $43$, asking the proctor, if there is one, I suppose is the only way about it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I countem them. But I cannot understand whether or not to include the number 43 in my count.

Comment: @scoopfaze Unfortunately, there's no way of asking the proctor right now.

Comment: I mean, I would hope so. Otherwise you'd be using an online resource during an exam!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define ''*the amount of primes numbers below $n$*'' as $\pi(n)$, the prime-counting function. Then the question ''*How many prime numbers are there from 43 to 60?*'' can be ''translated'' as
$$
\pi(60) - \pi(43),
$$
which is equal to $3$.

Comment: I'm not sure what this adds when the OP is clearly confused about whether or not $43$ should be included in the count.

Comment: @YiFan I'm trying to show that the answer depends on the definition. Here it involves $\pi(n)$, which then makes the solution clear.

Comment: Does "below $n$" mean $\lt n$ or $\le n$? The usual definition of $\pi(n)$ is the number of primes $\le n$  but that is not at all clear from your wording. Is $43$ below $43$?

Comment: @bof The ambiguity is left there on purpose.